# EF Core NOT NULL constraint failed on a nullable column

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework, asp.net-core

So for some reason my migrations broke after adding a one to one relationship in the models in ASP Core, the real problematic function is

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<long>(
            name: "RatingId",
            table: "ContentPosts",
            type: "INTEGER",
            nullable: true,
            defaultValue: null);

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Ratings",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<long>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                Commends = table.Column<long>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                Views = table.Column<long>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Ratings", x => x.Id);
            });

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_ContentPosts_RatingId",
            table: "ContentPosts",
            column: "RatingId");

    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_ContentPosts_Ratings_RatingId",
            table: "ContentPosts",
            column: "RatingId",
            principalTable: "Ratings",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.SetNull);
}
```

Where the last `AddForeignKey` method throws an error

> SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: ef_temp_ContentPosts.RatingId'

I've also set the default value of the `RatingId` to be `0L` and I get the error

> SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'

I've checked the database in DB Browser and `ContentPosts` still does not have the `RatingId` column and so it should be fine that nothing interferes with adding a new column named `RatingId`

Comment: Well, the column refers to `Id` values in existing `Ratings` records. Meaning: you can only populate the default value by an existing ID value. Or, of course, make it nullable, for the time being.

Comment: Do you use code first to add foreign key column?